# How do I check if a value is contained in a vector? C++

Tags: c++, vector, casting, most-vexing-parse

I have a vector that I am trying to perform a contains function on. I am receiving some sort of casting error and I can't piece together a solution. I am also wanting to know whether or not what I am doing is the appropriate way to check if a vector contains a value.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

static void someFunc(double** Y, int length);
static bool contains(double value, std::vector<double> vec);

int main()
{
    double doubleArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    double *pDoubleArray = doubleArray;
    int size = sizeof doubleArray / sizeof doubleArray[0];

    someFunc(&pDoubleArray, size);

    return 0;
}
static void someFunc(double** Y, int length)
{   
    std::vector<double> vec();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //error: 'contains' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'
        if(contains(*(Y[i]), vec)) 
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

}
static bool contains(double value, std::vector<double> vec)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vec[i] == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you declare a variable with it's default constructor, you don't put `()` after it (although it's optional when you use `new` to allocate space on the free store). So this line:

```
std::vector<double> vec();
```

should become

```
std::vector<double> vec;
```

If you leave it as you did, it thinks that line is a function prototype of a function called `vec` taking no parameters and returning a `std::vector<double>`, which is why you're getting a compiler error.

And yes, your code for finding an item will work (it's called a linear search). Also if you want to, you can use `std::find`:

```
if (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value) != vec.end())
    // found value in vec
```

If your vector is in sorted order, you can also use `binary_search` which is much faster than `find`, and the usage is the same *except* `binary_search` returns a `bool` instead of an iterator (so you don't need to test it against `vec.end()`). Make sure you include the `algorithm` header if you use either of these.

Comment: Awesome, works great! Thanks to others also who had overlapping answers!

Comment: FYI, std::find returns the last element if the match isn't found, which is why `!= vec.end()` is there

Comment: `vec.end()` doesn't return the last element, it returns the [past-the-end](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/) element. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to match the final item.

Answer (score 7):

```
std::vector<double> vec();
```

Oddly, this does *not* declare a `vector` using the default constructor. This declares a function taking no arguments and returning a `vector`.  Try this instead:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
```

Comment: This is a good point, but doesn't answer the question.  I may have upvoted anyways because it was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) to check an STL datastructure to contain a certain value.